# angularJS JSON parsing

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and trying to parse the data and display it on a page.

```
{
"count": 13,
"status": 200,
"statusMessage": "OK",
"userContact": [
    {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "universityId": 1,
            "email": "test@harbingergroup.com",
            "password": "",
            "phoneNo": "1234567890",
            "gender": "M",
            "userType": 1,
            "medicalComments": "",
            "dob": "2015-02-22",
            "universityAffiliation": 1,
            "cityId": "1"
        },
        "userContactList": {
            "count": 2,
            "status": 200,
            "statusMessage": "OK",
            "contact": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "userId": 1,
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "lastName": "user",
                    "phoneNo": "9876543210",
                    "email": "test@example.com"
                },
                {
                    "id": 24,
                    "userId": 1,
                    "firstName": "first1",
                    "lastName": "last1",
                    "phoneNo": "9876543210",
                    "email": "test@example.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

this is my JSON data.What i am trying is :

```
<tr ng-repeat="studentDetails in studentProfileData">
```

`studentDetails.status` for getting status and   `studentDetails.userContacts.firstName` for first name
 but I am not getting the data. What is wrong here?

Comment: According to what you have above `userContacts.firstName` should be `userContact[0].user.firstName`

Comment: but what is the need of [0] if i am using ng-repeat.and how do i access status then

Comment: That depends on the data structure. You presumably have a list of contacts, if all of the list items in `studentProfileData` have only 1 `userContact` than you could always use `0`, otherwise you may have to have another `ng-repeat`. It all depends on the data structure and exactly how you want it displayed.

Comment: and how to access status then..simply by {{status}}.where do i use studentDetails?

Comment: Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/7ywoLzk8/1/), it is hard to help when I feel like I am missing information. So I built a quick little example

Comment: Seems more like an issue of understanding how arrays and objects work and where you are in the nesting at each level of ng-repeat and what entity exists at that level

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that studentProfileData contains a list of users (userContact):

```
studentDetails.user.firstName
```

will contain "test"